Fixed Amount of Minting per block?
If i want to mint specific amount of native coin by the end of every block where should i implement the logic . Do i customize the pallet-template using pallet hooks , or do i implement a existing pallet (If there is please let me know? ).

Yes, this is possible. The Darwinia Crab network uses such logic.
We have a customized staking pallet. For your purposes, this could be any pallet that handles inflation, such as pallet-inflation or pallet-reward. Our approach is to distribute rewards to the stakers every session through this pallet.

Staking Pallet Code

We also have an IssuingManager interface to configure the issuing method for different networks (including reward calculation). If you don't need network-specific configurations, you can embed this logic directly into the pallet.
As shown in our code, we do not perform any calculations here. For the Darwinia Crab network, we return a fixed amount of 20_000 per session, which translates to a fixed amount minted per block.

Crab Network Staking Code

Furthermore, we automatically dispatch the reward to one staking exposure per block. If you're interested, check the code below. The most common method is allowing stakers to claim the reward manually.

https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/b782fa30af83270d9048f4ddffdb9f4514c0b913/pallet/staking/src/lib.rs#L350-L354

